# Accessing X-Requested-With Header with Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: ajax, oracle, plsql

I'm trying to differentiate AJAX requests from standard HTTP requests in a Oracle PL/SQL environment (Oracle 10g DB).  I have added **X-Requested-With** to my **PlsqlCGIEnvironmentList** and indeed see a value when I print the CGI variables with `owa_util.print_cgi_env;`.

Here is an example:

```
PLSQL_GATEWAY = WebDb
GATEWAY_IVERSION = 3
SERVER_SOFTWARE = Oracle-Application-Server-10g/10.1.2.0.2 Oracle-HTTP-Server
GATEWAY_INTERFACE = CGI/1.1
SERVER_PORT = 7779
SERVER_NAME = myserver.com
REQUEST_METHOD = GET
QUERY_STRING = action=change_contact&doc_id=10032
PATH_INFO = /!fc
SCRIPT_NAME = /script
REMOTE_ADDR = 172.30.170.125
SERVER_PROTOCOL = HTTP/1.1
REQUEST_PROTOCOL = HTTP
REMOTE_USER = myuser
HTTP_USER_AGENT = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
HTTP_HOST = myserver.com
HTTP_ACCEPT = text/html, */*; q=0.01
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE = en-US,en;q=0.5
HTTP_REFERER = http://myserver.com/script/!fc?action=doc&doc_id=10032
HTTP_ORACLE_ECID = 175007308883,1
HTTP_ORACLE_CACHE_VERSION = 10.1.2
WEB_AUTHENT_PREFIX =
DAD_NAME = script
DOC_ACCESS_PATH = docs
DOCUMENT_TABLE = wpg_document
PATH_ALIAS =
REQUEST_CHARSET = WE8MSWIN1252
REQUEST_IANA_CHARSET = WINDOWS-1252
SCRIPT_PREFIX =
X-Requested-With = XMLHttpRequest
HTTP_COOKIE = SMIDENTITY=0emF6I4...
```

The problem is, `owa_util.get_cgi_env('X-Requested-With')` is always null even for requests like the one above that shows `X-Requested-With = XMLHttpRequest`

Any idea what my problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to 10g, but I looked at the OWA_UTIL code in 11gR2.
The item of interest is the UPPER function being applied in get_cgi_env.
It is possible that in 10g, it is doing the UPPER on one end of the comparison but not the other, so any variable including lowercase isn't matching.

```
   procedure print_cgi_env is
   begin
      for i in 1..owa.num_cgi_vars
      loop
         htp.print(owa.cgi_var_name(i)||' = '||owa.cgi_var_val(i)||htf.nl);
      end loop;
   end;

   function get_cgi_env(param_name in varchar2) return varchar2 is
      upper_param_name varchar2(2000) := upper(param_name);
   begin
      for i in 1..owa.num_cgi_vars
      loop
         if (upper(owa.cgi_var_name(i)) = upper_param_name)
           then return(owa.cgi_var_val(i));
         end if;
      end loop;

      return NULL;
   end;
```

Check your OWA_UTIL.